Why does SQL Server prefer clustered index seek over non-clustered index scan?
Create table:
CREATE TABLE  AGENTS 
( 
    AGENT_CODE CHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    AGENT_NAME CHAR(40), 
    WORKING_AREA CHAR(35), 
    COMMISSION INT, 
    PHONE_NO CHAR(15), 
    COUNTRY NVARCHAR(25) 
);

Put data into it:
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A007', 'Ramasundar', 'Bangalore', '15', '077-25814763', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A003', 'Alex ', 'London', '13', '075-12458969', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A008', 'Alford', 'New York', '12', '044-25874365', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A011', 'Ravi Kumar', 'Bangalore', '15', '077-45625874', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A010', 'Santakumar', 'Chennai', '14', '007-22388644', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A012', 'Lucida', 'San Jose', '12', '044-52981425', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A005', 'Anderson', 'Brisban', '13', '045-21447739', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A001', 'Subbarao', 'Bangalore', '14', '077-12346674', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A002', 'Mukesh', 'Mumbai', '11', '029-12358964', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A006', 'McDen', 'London', '15', '078-22255588', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A004', 'Ivan', 'Torento', '15', '008-22544166', '');
INSERT INTO AGENTS VALUES ('A009', 'Benjamin', 'Hampshair', '11', '008-22536178', '');

Create a non-clustered index on column AGENT_CODE and include AGENT_NAME:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NON_CLUS_IX_AGENTS_AGENTCODE_AGENTNAME]
ON [dbo].[AGENTS] ([AGENT_CODE])
INCLUDE (AGENT_NAME)

If I select the AGENT_CODE and AGENT_NAME columns only, why is SQL Server using the clustered index seek, instead of a non-clustered scan?

However, if I select data without a WHERE clause, it then selects data using a non-clustered scan. Why does SQL Server not use the non-clustered index at first, even if we have all the columns that are being requested by the query are present within non-clustered index data structure?


Maybe because you don't have enough rows for it to make any real difference. Try using a million rows and see what happens.

And why are you using LIKE with no wildcards instead of =?

the clustered index is unique on CODE, so sql server knows that it only needs to read one row for the first statement, but only if it fetches by PK. The NC clustered is not unique on CODE, so it doesn't know how many rows it has (unless it has time to generate stats that is, then it might know). In the second case, it has to fetch all rows, but NC index contains less data so it's cheaper to scan than the Clustered PK. But agree with @DaleK, this naive explanation doesn't always work for larger data

Oh I've just realised that when you say "why SQL server is using the clustered index seek, instead of Non clustered scan?" you actually mean  "why SQL server is using the clustered index seek, instead of Non clustered seek?" as both are on the same key column (and same applies to the question title) - rather than actually wanting it to scan instead of seek?
